# How do I read a file in NodeJS whose URL is stored in my database?

Tags: node.js

When I try to read a file that is stored in the database, node gives me an error saying:

`"error": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'http://localhost:8000/assets/uploadNk2i8BAE81Wp6pFI6TtF-.pdf'"`

But, when I visit that link in the browser, I can see the pdf file. So, why is node failing to read the file?

This is my code:

```
fs.readFileSync(req.user.resume, 'utf-8', (err,data) => {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            else {
                res.send(data);
            }
        })
```

Comment: path.join(__dirname, '/assets'); do like this

Comment: fetching a file over http though a browser is not the same as accessing a local file with fs, you need remove the `http://localhost:8000` part to make the path local, use path resolve and check file exists etc all before attempting to load it

Comment: readFileSync with an async callback? That's unheard of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Sorry, I didn't know before that the fs could only read local files. And I have corrected the readFileSync method also so everything's working now. Thanks for the help. 

Now, how do I mark this question as solved?